# Android ProgressBar onclick

Tags: android

I have a progress bar that I want to click on and move the progress to the point clicked.

i have

```
    pb = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    pb.setOnClickListener(new ProgressBar.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
            //
       }
    }
```

Basically I want it to behave like a SeekBar, but I need to use a progress bar because I am using a circular progress bar, and the code I have visually fits my needs.

cheers,

Comment: Better to search on _Google_

Comment: check it http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-progress-bar-example/

Comment: That does not help, that is just a progress bar with a button, I need to click on the progress bar and get the position clicked

Comment: if u have that type of requirement better to use seekbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with a custom seekbar
https://github.com/JesusM/HoloCircleSeekBar/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/com/jesusm/holocircleseekbar/lib/HoloCircleSeekBar.java

This is a circular seekbar, as per my requirements